# JS. Как в зависимости от переменной, сделать активным пункт <select

Tags: javascript

Суть в чем, есть выпадающий список на странице

```
<select onselect="previewLink(this.value)" name="path_list" id="path_list" class="selforma">
<option value="">Не выбрано</option>
<option value="Форма Автошкола">Форма Автошкола</option>
<option value="Форма ИП № 1 (месяц)">Форма ИП № 1 (месяц)</option>
<option value="Форма № 4 такси">Форма № 4 такси</option>
<option value="Форма № 4 такси СДС">Форма № 4 такси СДС</option>
<option value="Форма № 3 большая">Форма № 3 большая</option>
<option value="Форма № 3 большая (месяц)">Форма № 3 большая (месяц)</option>
<option value="Форма № 3 большая СДС">Форма № 3 большая СДС</option>
<option value="Форма № 3 большая СДС (месяц)">Форма № 3 большая СДС (месяц)</option>
<option value="Форма № 3 маленькая">Форма № 3 маленькая</option>
<option value="Форма Грузовая">Форма Грузовая</option>
<option value="Форма Грузовая (месяц)">Форма Грузовая (месяц)</option>
<option value="Форма Грузовая СДС">Форма Грузовая СДС</option>
<option value="Форма Грузовая СДС (месяц)">Форма Грузовая СДС (месяц)</option>
<option value="Форма Специальная СДС">Форма Специальная СДС</option>
</select>
```

на этой же странице есть подключенный скрипт который получает JSON данные, изменяет некоторые значения в форме.

пример:

```
document.querySelector('#path_list_last_iteration').innerHTML = "Последний №: " + JSON.parse(response.result).last_iteration;
document.querySelector('#path_list_last_date').innerHTML = "Последняя дата: " + JSON.parse(response.result).last_date;
document.querySelector('#dates-table').style.display = "block";
document.querySelector('#dates-table-license-expire').innerHTML = JSON.parse(response.result).license_expire;
```

задача, сделать активным пункт селекта в зависимости от параметра path_list
в сам JSON я это значение добавил, оно скрипту передается, а вот как активировать нужный пункт списка никак не могу сделать (((

пробовал вот так сделать, но не работает (((

```
function getLastPathListData(organization_short_name, callName) {
 let params = [
{key: "short_name", value: organization_short_name.replace(/"/g, """)},
{key: "call_name", value: callName}
 ];
 if (document.querySelector('#find_organization_docs').value.length > 0 && document.querySelector('#find_driver_from_call_name_docs').value.length > 0) {
request(HOST_NAME+"scripts/getLastPathListData.php", JSON.stringify(params), function (result) {
let response = JSON.parse(result);
document.querySelector('#path_list_from').value = JSON.parse(response.result).new_date;
if(JSON.parse(response.result).new_date >= JSON.parse(response.result).max_date_to) {
 document.querySelector('#path_list_to').value = JSON.parse(response.result).max_date_to;
} else {
 document.querySelector('#path_list_to').value = JSON.parse(response.result).new_date;
}
document.querySelector('#path_list_last_iteration').innerHTML = "Последний №: " + JSON.parse(response.result).last_iteration;
document.querySelector('#path_list_last_date').innerHTML = "Последняя дата: " + JSON.parse(response.result).last_date;
document.querySelector('#dates-table').style.display = "block";
document.querySelector('#dates-table-license-expire').innerHTML = JSON.parse(response.result).license_expire;

const select = document.querySelector('#path_list').getElementsByTagName('option');

for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
if (select[i].value === JSON.parse(response.result).path_list) select[i].selected = true;
}
document.querySelector('#dates-table-inspection-expire').innerHTML = JSON.parse(response.result).inspection_expire;
document.querySelector('#dates-table-osago-expire').innerHTML = JSON.parse(response.result).osago_expire;


console.log(response);
console.log(params);
}, false);
} else {........
```

то есть этот код

```
const select = document.querySelector('#path_list').getElementsByTagName('option');
for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
if (select[i].value === JSON.parse(response.result).path_list) select[i].selected = true;
}
```

не дал результата, а как сделать по другому не знаю, ли где допустил ошибку....

Скажу честно, я больше по ПХП, в яваскриптах почти не разбираюсь, а сделать нужно (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var response = {
  result: '{ "path_list": "Two" }'
};
var data = JSON.parse(response.result);
//...
document.getElementById('path_list').value = data.path_list;
```

```html
<select id="path_list">
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
  <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Супер!!!! Очень выручили! Спасибо!!!!

Comment: @arashvg Пожалуйста. Успехов!